# Constant value not changing when recompiling referenced assembly

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, constants

I have this code in an assembly:

```
public class Class1
{
    public const int x = 10;
}
```

and in a **different** assembly I have:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Class1.x);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Of course the output was `10`, but then I changed `x` to `20`:

```
public class Class1
{
    public const int x = 20;
}
```

I recompiled the assembly and moved it to my command line program's bin directory. However, the output of my program was still `10`, until I compiled assembly containing the `main` function.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Constants values in C# are in-lined in place where they are used. I.e. line `Console.WriteLine(Class1.x);` will be compiled to `Console.WriteLine(10);`. Generated IL-code will look like:

```
  .entrypoint
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.s   10  // here just integer value 10 is loaded on stack
  IL_0003:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
```

There will not be any link to Class1. So, until you re-compile `Main` assembly, it will have in-lined value `10`. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx) has warning about this case of constants usage:

> Don’t create a constant to represent information that you expect to
>   change at any time. For example, don’t use a constant field to store
>   the price of a service, a product version number, or the brand name of
>   a company. These values can change over time, and because compilers
>   propagate constants, other code compiled with your libraries will have
>   to be recompiled to see the changes.

They mention that constant expressions are evaluated only at compile time. I.e. `Class1.x` will be evaluated at `Main` assembly compile time to value `10`. And without re-compilation that value will not change. But unfortunately it does not clearly explains reason of such behavior (to me at least).

BTW [Named and Optional parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) values are also in-lined in place where method is called, and you also need to re-compile caller assembly to update values.

Comment: @Aschratt nope, they are not in-lined. Readonly fields are simple fields, with only one difference - they can be assigned only during declaration or in constructor of class which holds them. They are loaded with `ldsfld` (if static) or `ldfld` instruction, and their value is evaluated at runtime, not at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

This is a technique called **constant folding** used in compiling. In short, the compiler look for values that can be determined at compile time, computes those values, and write them *directly* in the exe file. This speeds up the execution of the final machine code. This technique applies to other many compiled languages, such as C, C++ as well.

Comment: The last sentence is actually wrong, I think. In C/C++ `const` is a field modifier that is used to make a field *appear* constant. Real substitution like in this case is only possible through symbolic constants (`#define ONE 1`). Constant fields *can* also be modified, using their address.

Comment: **constant folding** does not mean the keyword has to be `const`. Try the following: write `int x = 1 + 2 + 3;` in C++, compile with optimizations enabled, then decompile the exe. You won't find it says `mov eax 1;add eax 2;add eax 3;`.