# Is there a difference in performance between 'const' and 'var' declarations in Roslyn?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, roslyn

In a .NET application, there's a definitive performance difference between these two ways of declaring a string value:

1. `const string MyConst = "value";`
2. `var MyConst = "value";`

The former (#1) is a compile-time declaration so there is no performance loss at runtime, compared to the latter (#2) which will allocate and initialize a `String` object every time that line of code is executed.

In my project I utilize Roslyn to compile user-specified C# scripts using `CSharpCodeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource`, extract the relevant methods (`MethodInfo` objects) and keep them around in memory to be invoked later as needed.

My question is, do the aforementioned performance differences still apply in this case?  Are `const`, `static` and other statements that are normally compile-time, still behave in that fashion when a script is compiled and executed in-memory, as described above?

Comment: Strings are interned.  I doubt you will see any meaningful difference.

Comment: Are you interested in `const` _generally_? Or `const string` _specifically_?

Comment: @mjwills, I was thinking generally, but didn't realize there was a qualitative difference/something special about 'const string' as opposed to 'const anything-else'...?

Comment: The main 'downside' of `const` generally is that the the value gets inlined whenever used - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24227690/constant-value-not-changing-when-recompiling-referenced-assembly . This can mean your final binaries are larger than if you didn't use `const`. In practice, you are incredibly unlikely to experience issues due to this.

Comment: It makes no difference.  You have to use the const *somewhere*, it will look like var something = MyConst;  Which is exactly the same as the 2nd statement.  The metadata is a wee bigger for the 1st statement since it has to store the const definition, the perf deterioration due to the less efficient usage of VM is not measurable.