# Why does a const int change?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, debugging, constants

[image: Code]

My code errors and debugging clearly shows the incorrect value of a const int. Below you can see that I'm not modifying the const variable(not that I'm able anyways).
If I breakpoint early in the execution of my code, the const variable gets set correctly to 59. Somewhere along the lines, it just gets decremented by 1 apparently.

I...don't even know where to start looking. This sort of thing just isn't supposed to happen, right?

Comment: Hi I don't think that your links work, you can check the preview in the editor to see if it has worked, I've edited for you

Comment: @JamesGill link always worked for me, but I approved your edit anyway.

Comment: make it  a property, and in the setter set sa break point so you can see whats going on

Comment: please post the code instead of a screenshot!

Comment: I downvoted because posting code as a screenshot makes the question harder to find for people with a similar situation and is massively less accessible to users of screen readers.

Comment: I believe there is absolutely no point in posting code in an issue like this because the whole problem revolves around the declaration of a const variable and a subsequent modification of it's value, all of which is a single line of code. The screenshot was there to affirm the validity of my claim, as I found it a bit incongruous for such a behavior to occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code probably lives in a class library which your main application compiles against.

You're debugging with the most recent code, but the point with `const` is that it is embedded in the call site. So the **caller** still has the old `2018 - 1960 = 58` value. If you claim that the debugger sometimes shows you the new `59` value, then that must be in the class library itself, which is compiled against itself, so holds the new value.

It's not that the const changes, it's that it *doesn't* change, hence the name. Recompile the calling application.

See also [Constant value not changing when recompiling referenced assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24227690/constant-value-not-changing-when-recompiling-referenced-assembly).